# Chrome Dev console: JS code to open tab and execute js snippet in new Tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, console.log

Is it possible to open a tab from the console and inject some code in the console over there? I want to automate a process of opening a batch of links from a HTML table (iterate over them using jQuery-selector -> open every link in a new tab) and than execute some script in the newly opened tab.

If possible, best-case, also wait for the script to finish and than close the tab again.

Possible or do I need to write a minimum injection plugin or use something like greasemonkey!?

Comment: I think even if it is possible with [`Target.createTarget`](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Target/#method-createTarget) the task is too complex to be handled purely in DevTools Console. have you considered using Node.Js with [puppeteer](https://pptr.dev/) instead?

Comment: Thanks, it's a great idea. Would also be possible using python and selenium, which I'm a fan of. Unfortunately it was just meant as a way to help some friends every now and than with their tasks without them having to install anything and with just copy pasting some lines of code into console. Maybe I'll check out the createTarget functionality